# 68000 - How can I build a file executable on a Macintosh Plus from a 68000 assembly source code?

Tags: assembly, 68000

I worked on a java sub-language compiler recently. This compiler provides a 68000 assembly file. I used easy68k to test and improve it. Now I want to go to the next level and try it on a real Macintosh Plus emulator: Mini vMac.

So my question is: what can I do to build an executable file from my 68000 assembly file ?

I know that the file must have a .dsk extension. Files in .dsk found online works on Mini vMac but I can't manage to get one myself.
(I did a lot of research without finding the way...)

Thanks a lot for your time and attention ;)

Comment: You'll need to generate a Macintosh executable and then create a disk image that includes the executable. To generate the executable you'll need to find a cross-compiling tool chain that supports generating Macintosh Plus executables on your OS. You can then copy the resulting executable to a disk image using one of the methods described on the Mini vMac site: http://www.gryphel.com/c/image/index.html Alternatively you could try using a Macintosh Plus hosted toolchain under the emulator itself, you'd then just need to copy your source code to the disk image.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done anything in 68k assembly yet, so I can't vouch for it, but [Retro68](https://github.com/autc04/Retro68) should have a 68k-compatible version of GNU Assembler and the rest of the tooling needed to make Macintosh applications with it, given its description and my understanding of GCC's architecture:

> A GCC-based cross-compilation environment for 68K and PowerPC Macs. Why? Because there is no decent C++17 Compiler targeting Apple's System 6. If that's not a sufficient reason for you, I'm sure you will find something more useful elsewhere.

According to the requirements, it runs on Linux, macOS, and, for Windows, via [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/). The README says the sample programs demonstrate how to produce BasiliskII/SheepShaver-compatible data/resource pairs, Executor-compatible AppleDouble pairs, MacBinary files, and HFS disk images.

Answer (score 0):

The classic 68k Macintosh (official) toolchain of choice was *[Metrowerks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodeWarrior) Code Warrior*. Without CW, you will be having a hard time developing for classic Macs (Pure 68k development toolchains typically lack the support for MacOS resource forks - note a Mac binary will not run without its proper resource fork). 
Unfortunately, recent editions of the toolchain (which is now owned by [NXP](http://www.nxp.com/)) no longer support 68k as a target - that support was officially dropped by 2005.

You might be best off to look for a second hand source Metrowerks compiler.

Another option for classic Mac development is the [Macintosh Programmer's Workshop (MPW)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macintosh_Programmer%27s_Workshop) that might possibly be available somewhere - It used to be a free download from the Apple sites once it became superseded by CW.

One more remark: Your question is probably better suited for the [Retrocomputing SE](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) site than SO

Comment: Don't forget MPW for assembly development

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already looked at MPW but there was a problem. If I remember correctly, it doesn't work on the current MacOS version since MacOS 9. But I will look at the MCW lead carefully. (Sorry, I didn't know the Retrocomputing SE site, thanks again).

Comment: You could always use an emulated older Mac to compile.

Comment: @Romzie Someone has apparently gotten [MPW to work on modern versions of OSX](https://github.com/ksherlock/mpw).